# Find the digit in hundred-thousandth place of sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion

Sum:   $1 + 3 + 9/2 + 27/6 + 81/24 + \ldots$

This is a problem on a competitive mathematics test, and I am trying to master the concept so I can understand when similar problems show up in future tests. Similar questions may ask for a digit in a different place, or a different type of sum, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Is this $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^n}{n!}$?

Comment: Yes! That's the formula for the summation

Comment: Are you allowed to use a computer?

Comment: If I may ask, how did you go about getting that relationship so quickly?

Comment: No, but we do get a calculator

Comment: @randomCoder May I ask, why you didn't specify the formula in the first place? Any finite suquence of numbers with unspcified rule can be extended arbitrarily ...

Comment: OK, to clarify, of the numerical result $20.d_1d_2d_3,\ldots$, do you want the hundred-thoudansth digit $d_{100000}$ or the digit $d_5$ that determines the hundred-thoudandths?

Comment: Try to recognise that this sum is $e^3$, and since you have a calculator...

Comment: This sum is $e^3.$

Comment: Sorry @HagenvonEitzen for not including the formula, I was not the one who found that out, and it was not specified in the problem, so I was wondering if there was a possible explanation on how to get that formula.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel how did you realize that the summation is e^3? Your thought process would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Dbchatto67 how did you realize that the summation is e^3? Your thought process would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @randomCoder An answer has been provided for you for that.

Comment: @randomCoder The problem is that if the formula is *not* part of the original problem statement, than the original problem statement is *ill-posed*.

Comment: @randomcoder I have already given the answer. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ about $x=0$ is $$e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^n} {n!},\ \text {for all }\ x \in \Bbb R.$$

Observe that your sum can be written as $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {3^n} {n!} = e^3.$$

Comment: THANK YOU @Dbchatto67 !!

Comment: You are most welcome @randomCoder.